# Geoserver and external website hosting

Tags: web, hosting, geoserver, wms

I have set up a webpage that calls wms from geoserver operating on localhost and using openlayers as a front end.  Everything works perfectly well.  The next step, however, causes a few issues.  My website is hosted on an external server by another company.  Therefore, when i upload the webpage it will not work, is there a way to solve this issue?  I only have access to the website through the ftp

cheers

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your service provider and ask about running GeoServer on the public webserver.  If you can't run GeoServer in an Internet-accessible place, then your options are severely limited.  Depending on how complicated/large your data is, you could consider generating a [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) dump of your data set and using OpenLayers' [vector styling](http://docs.openlayers.org/library/feature_styling.html) to perform the rendering client-side.  You could generate GeoJSON from GeoServer on your local machine and then upload it as a static file to your hosting provider.  OpenLayers would allow you to overlay this data on a publicly available tileset like Google Maps or OpenStreetMap.